# How do can I store/display the body of an email after selecting the email? (outlook 2013)

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I don't want to store/display the body of an email when I receive it.

What I want is to select my email and click an option that allows me to store/display the body.

So far my code displays the body of the email(twice?) when it is selected.

Here is the code..

```
namespace MailForwarder
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup
        (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook
            .ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler
            (CurrentExplorer_Event);
    }

    private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
    {
        Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder =
            this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
        String expMessage = "Your current folder is "
            + selectedFolder.Name + ".\n";
        try
        {
            if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
            {
                Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                {

                    Outlook.Explorer explorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
                    Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;

                    if (selection.Count > 0)   // Check that selection is not empty.
                    {
                        object selectedItem = selection[1];   // Index is one-based.
                        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;

                        if (mailItem != null)    // Check that selected item is a message.
                        {
                            String htmlBody = mailItem.HTMLBody;
                            String Body = mailItem.Body;
                            MessageBox.Show(Body);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            expMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }
 private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
 #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// From    Subject Received    Size    Categories  
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use multiple dots in the single line of code. Use System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. See [Systematically Releasing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

It seems you need to handle the [SelectionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813(v=office.15).aspx)  event of the Explorer class and get the list of selected emails. The event is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. It is also fired when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder.

The event is fired twice when the Reading pane is enabled in Outlook. If you turn it off, the event will be fired once.

[image]